# CSS styling checkbox when checked - not working

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have the following static html file, where I'm spending time building a CMS web application site for our client.

http://cms.tmadev.com.au/usergroup.html

In middle section, there's a vertical array of checkboxes (which I css-styled it) and I followed numerous online tutorials, which lead me to use this site link.

http://csscheckbox.com/

I download the source code tutorial, understood it, copied the css code, tailor my changes as per my client requirements.

Everything looks perfectly fine - except when trying to check the checkbox.

NOTHING HAPPENS!

The checkbox doesn't get checked when clicked!

I couldn't figure out why it's not working as it's supposed to be like the tutorial.

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Here's my code.

```
input[type=checkbox].input-checkbox{
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    margin: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}


input[type=checkbox].input-checkbox + label.input-label{
    border: 2px solid #58585A;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size:15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox].input-checkbox:checked + label.input-label{
    background-position: 0 -20px;   
}

.input-label{
    background-image: url('/images/tickbox.png');
}
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The CSS is fine. Your problem is matching the `label` elements with the `input` elements.

This method relies on the fact that clicking the `label` toggles the checkbox. If the `label` isn't attatched to the checkbox it won't work. Match the value of each `label`'s `for` attribute to the `id` of each checkbox.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox1" class="input-label"></label>
```

[**LIVE EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jUa3P/1/)

Comment: Wow, that was quick response! 

And I just fixed it - ha!  That explains why I'm supposed to get this label elements and input elements to match. I ignored that part, never realising this is what I'm supposed to use in the first place.  Thanks all! :)

Comment: I'm having this issue but this isn't the reason why, I have a feeling it's because I'm using handlebars to generate a template client side which contains the checkboxes. This only happens on smaller screen sizes, at larger sizes where the it isn't using the client side template it works fine. Would appreciate any insight...

Answer (score 1):

The `label` elements in your HTML have the wrong value in their `for` attributes.
Each `label` must have a `for` attribute value exactly matching the `id` of the checkbox it is meant to activate.

Answer (score 1):

The for attribute on your label needs to match the id of your input. This is working for me:

```
<div class="inputfield">                        
<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox1" class="input-label"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<label>                        
   <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
   <span class="input-label">Your Label</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score -2):

you have to change your label for id 
   here is working fiddle
 i have change your this line

```
<label for="checkbox2" class="input-label"></label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jUa3P/146/